# Video output Ubuntu 18.04.03LTS and Ryzen 2200G

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, amd-processor

I am trying to solve a problem. I just build a simple system for my daughter who needs some kind of HTPC. She doesn’t game. So I assembled that :

- CPU : AMD Ryzen 3 2200G 3.5 GHz
- Cooler : Noctua NH-L9a-AM4 33.84 CFM
- Motherboard : MSI B450I GAMING PLUS AC Mini ITX AM4
- Memory : Crucial Ballistix Sport LT 16 GB (2 x 8 GB) DDR4-3200
- Storage : Crucial MX500 1 TB 2.5" SSD
- Case : In Win Chopin HTPC Case w/150 W Power Supply
- OS: Ubuntu 18.04.03
- Compatibility: No issues or incompatibilities found on Pcpartpicker

MSI motherboard was flashed to last AMI BIOS 7A40vAA (2019/09/25). Tested on Ubuntu 18.04.03LTS with a monitor IIYAMA b2483hs B3 and on dual screen with a TV 55 inches PANASONIC TX-55GX610E, both fairly recent products. Connexion to monitor is through an adaptator DVI to HDMI, and HDMI to TV.

PROBLEMS : On single screen the monitor shows `out of range` on start up, impossible to access the BIOS either whith <kbd>DEL</kbd> or <kbd>F2</kbd> key. After a while boots on Ubuntu.

On dual screen, TV shows the BIOS but doesn’t boot Ubuntu (black screen) while the monitor shows `out of range`.

I tested the system out of the case with an old video card (NVIDIA GTX 960). Everything works properly. But I can’t add a video card in the IN WIN Chopin.
The Ryzen r3 2200G is supposed to adress this specific HTPC need. Does anybody else had to solve this problems ?

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer, thanks to Sabina from Panasonic:

On this TV, enter "sources" HDMI, select "enhanced". Its a question of compatibility with HDMI2. With this option enabled, Raven Ridge works perfectly.

Waiting for an answer from Iiyama.